# What is the optimal order of members in a class?

Tags: c++, optimization

If I have the following class:

```
class Example
{
  bool m_b1;
  SomeClass m_sc;  
  bool m_b2;
  char * m_name;
  bool m_b3;
  int m_i1;
  SomeClass * m_sc;
  int m_i2;
};
```

What is the optimal order of members? As far as I know, the order of declaration of members equals the order of members in memory, when creating an instance of this class.

- Should I sort the members so that equal types are together?
- Do all pointers count as the same type?
- Does rearrangement have an effect on the size of the object? Does 4 or 8 byte alignment apply here?
- How can I see the effects of the above? Does sizeof show the memory used by an object including empty space for alignment?
- Is it better at the end of the day to sort the members so that their meaning and context is easier to understand?

Comment: Unless you're programming for an embedded system with very little memory I would argue that order doesn't matter much. Only if you have arrays or a *lot* of member variables (in which case I would say your design is wrong) so that it can cause caching problems and the code is extremely time-critical (which is seldom the case), only then should you start thinking about grouping and order. Start by prioritizing readability (which implies maintainability), and only change if you absolutely need to.

Comment: I'd argue that the overlall size of the object has effect on runtime much more that where you member is declared. all the members are excessed by the CPU by calculating `this+offset` at compile time, so in runtime there is no much of a difference

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a rule of thumb you should order by size, greater to smaller. This will create the minimum padding of the structure, thus minimizing the structure size. This matters most if objects of the structure are used in a contiguous allocated memory, e.g. vector and helps a lot with cache (more objects fit in the same cache line).

Another surprising optimization demonstrated by Andrei Alexandrescu (I think was in one of CppCon) is that he brought the most accessed member first. This is faster because the offset is zero. Of course he was talking about micro-optimization, after benchmarking the hell out of the application and caring for every little strop of performance.

Comment: Do you know where the "greater-to-smaller" ordering comes from? I believe you get the same size by the inverse "smaller-to-greater" ordering, plus you have more members at a small offset.

Comment: @davidhigh I don't know where the ordering comes from. I've heard from several places (one of my teachers, some conferences on the web). I think you are right, smaller-to-greater would yield the same size. The "small offset" is irrelevant. The optimization comes from the fact that the offset is zero (not from how small the offset is). On the ALU, operations with `0` are faster. I think that also with `1` (increment for instance). Other than that, the operand doesn't matter (if it is `4`, `10` or `32`).

Answer (score 8):

The order is important when a member variable depends on another member variable when using initializer lists:

Imagine a class with two variable where the constructor of the second variable (varC) needs the first (varB)

```
class A
{
    B varB;
    C varC;

    A()
    : varC(varB)
    {
    }
};
```

The order decides in which steps the constructors are executed, so changing the order of varB and varC will pass a uninitialized object of varB to varC.

Of course, style and readability are also important.

Comment: Irrespective of the code snippet, I think this point is rather good.

Comment: Sorry, I used the wrong type of snippet, so it seems :)

Answer (score 3):

> Should I sort the members so that equal types are together?

If it increases readability, Yes!

> Do all pointers count as the same type?

Yes, all pointers should take either 32bit or 64bit or whatever the system defines.

> Does rearrangement have an effect on the size of the object? Does 4 or
>   8 byte alignment apply here?

This is possible, because of alignment. [Live example](http://cpp.sh/7kwj6).

> Is it better at the end of the day to sort the members so that their
>   meaning and context is easier to understand?

If it increases meaning, readability and maintainability, YES.

Answer (score 1):

A good rule of thumb that I've learned is "place the largest variables first".

In your example this would be

```
   class Example
{

  SomeClass m_sc; 
  SomeClass * m_sc;
  char * m_name;
  int m_i1;
  int m_i2;
  bool m_b1;
  bool m_b2;
  bool m_b3;
};
```

I'm not the best at formulating my thoughts, so bear with me.

Variables can generally only be placed so that they are aligned with their own size, which would mean that if we placed a int between any of the last three booleans the compiler would have to pad sizeof(int) - sizeof(bool) bytes to make sure that the data fits its alignment. Which would mean that you would use up more memory than you need.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers mentioned before:

The order of the member variables is mostly relevant (as I have seen) in data-oriented design, for example in video game engines. You basically want to minimize cache misses.

A very good article regarding data-oriented design can be found here: [Data-Oriented Design (Or Why You Might Be Shooting Yourself in The Foot With OOP)](http://gamesfromwithin.com/data-oriented-design)