# Is there a quick way to know a class member's accessibility of a huge class?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, intellisense, access-modifiers, visual-assist

I'm using Visual Studio with Visual Assist.

I found if a class gets too big, you have to scroll up to check the access modifiers to know if the method or variable is public, protected, or etc. It takes some time and the access modifier could be missed if you scroll too fast.

Is there a way, like a short cut or sth in Intellisense/Visual Assist, to let me know a member's accessibility immediately?

(Scenario: exploring Unreal Engine source code...)

Comment: Break down in smaller classes. God Objects are bad (amongst others for this reason).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Not sure poor old Tom wants to work for Epic Games.

Comment: Some IDE's (e.g. Visual Studio IIRC, maybe Eclipse also) also have a little treeview showing the class members odered by their visibility (or alphabetically) for quick navigation.

Comment: Just `#define private public` before including the headers. Now, you can rest assured that all the members are public :-)

Comment: @Jeffrey: Alas that's undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Bathsheba that was in jest. But I've seen production code for a financial institution that depended on it.... scarry

Comment: @Jeffrey: RBS ?

Answer (score 1):

There would be no problem to add the visibility before each class member like this:

```
class Foo {
    public:    float foobaz1();
    public:    void foobaz2();

    protected: int baz1();
    protected: std::string baz2();

    private:   int bar1();
    private:   double bar2();
};
```

Unusual<sup>1</sup>, but syntactically correct.

---

OK as you mention Unreal-Engine as a project that's out of your control.
For such I'd try to find a decent IDE, that supports a compact tree view, which shows all class members ordered by scope, alhpabetically (or other criterie) for quick navigation.

Any IDE, that supports intellisense should have such feature because the code needs to be roughly parsed anyways.

I am pretty sure that Visual Studio supports that (not sure about VS Code). Eclipse may be, I can't remember, I use such fancy stuff rarely anyways, and usually prefer to break stuff down in smaller units.

Other preferred method:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>, type *public*, get there, and look down. Faster than *scrolling* at least.

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>The c++ guys will sent you to the Java penalty corner though.</sub>

Comment: As I recall, there is, or perhaps was, a slight difference: the compiler's permitted to reorder data members at accessibility-label boundaries.  Hmmm. You didn't show any data members in your example. Still, in OP's use this might break some layout compatibility, no?

Comment: @jthill Would work for data members (class member variables) the same way. Nothing would be broken with class layout or such. I don't fully understand your concern at all TBH.

Comment: I see, it's the accessibility itself that matters, not label presence.  [Here's what I was remembering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36149462/does-public-and-private-have-any-influence-on-the-memory-layout-of-an-object), it's been relaxed since.

Comment: @jthill I never said to change the already existing visibility, but just repeating it for each and every member BTW.

Comment: Right. With C++03 that would have allowed arbitrary layout reordering for whatever inscrutable reasons they had for that, possibly breaking an external toolchain set up for the existing one.